# Node process memory usage exceeds --max_old_space_size

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, puppeteer

I'm having trouble limiting a node processes memory usage.

I am running an application on AWS and the servers crash when the memory usage exceeds what is available. I have tried using the `--max_old_space_size` flag but the process seems to still use more memory than the value I specify in the flag and the server crashes.

I'm fine with the process failing I just really need the server not to crash.

I know that the flag is working because if I specify `--max_old_space_size=1` the node script is killed immediately.

My question is, are there other ways to limit the memory usage of a node process (and its sub processes?) I'm running on `ubuntu` and have heard `cgroups` could maybe achieve this? Or am I doing something wrong? Are there other flags for node processes that would limit overall memory usage?

Comment: Define *"the server crashes"* please.

Comment: Using `htop` the memory reaches that allocated to the EC2 instance and the server no longer responds to stuff like `ssh` it just hangs. There are probably more diagnostics that I could run to understand why AWS EC2's do that in general but they don't seem to react well to applications that try to use more memory than has been allocated. TBH I have always had that issue with EC2 instances, you have to be really careful with memory usage or you get shut out and can't get back in. Either way my problem is with the node process running away with memory usage not necessarily the internals of EC2s

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.